# please help in making a python 3 program to determine if a number is a palindrome

Tags: python

A palindrome, that is, it remains the same when its digits are reversed, like 404. I've tried using the if loop:

```
a=list(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
if x in a:
    a[0:2]=a[4:6]
    print(a, 'is a palindrome')
else:
    print(a, 'not a palindrome')
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to check if the reverse order is equal to the correct one:

```
n = input()
if n == n[::-1]:
  print(f"{n} is a palindrome")
```

Comment: Please keep in mind its just minimum working example which shows the logic. Think about what should happen if someone inputs a space " " or how to handle other things.

Comment: where can I get resources to learn about such, and how to transform input characters using leet?